# ES6 map array to string without comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to map a list of errors into a list that I will show in a tooltip. The list added, but there's a `,` added between every li element.

I guess this is because this basically does `errors.map(error => ...).toString()` in the end. Any ideas how I can map the strings in `errors` array without having this comma added?

```
data-tip = {`
  Precisa de corrigir os seguintes problemas antes de publicar o anúncio:</br>
  <ul>
    ${errors.map(error => `<li>${error}</li>`)}
  </ul>
`}
```

Comment: just replace to this and see: `${errors.map(error => <li>${error}</li>)}` remove the backtics of li.

Answer (score 40):

`.toString()` of the array object uses `Array.prototype.join` method for converting the array into a string. The `.join` method by default uses `,` for joining the elements. You can replace the `.toString()` with `.join('')`.

Comment: in addition to this post, check also [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) doc.

Answer (score 29):

In your code, you are using template literals which returns you a string and hence the code

```
 ${errors.map(error => `<li>${error}</li>`)}
```

is converted to a string using a `toString()` function which by default joins the returned array with a `,`.

You can make use of join with anly other separator like

```
{`
  Precisa de corrigir os seguintes problemas antes de publicar o anúncio:</br>
  <ul>
    ${errors.map(error => `<li>${error}</li>`).join(' ')}
  </ul>
`}
```

Comment: You have an error here. `.join(' ')` should be inside the brackets

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way ::

```
let arrayOfStr = [10, 20, 45, 12, 65 ];

let myNumberOfStr = arrayOfStr.map( number => `myNumber_${number}` ).join(' ');

console.log(myNumberOfStr); 
// "myNumber_10 myNumber_20 myNumber_45 myNumber_12 myNumber_65"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `reduce`. Like this:

```js
data-tip = {`
  Precisa de corrigir os seguintes problemas antes de publicar o anúncio:</br>
  <ul>
    ${errors.reduce(
      (prevError, currentError) => `${prevError}<li>${currentError}</li>`, '',
    )}
  </ul>
`}
```